# How can I make my site available in specific countries or block some of them?

Tags: ngrok, tunnel, tunneling, http-tunneling

I own a html website page and show it to my clients with ngrok. But unfortunately, my page is being leaked outside and to other people. then my information is being stolen

So I do not want my page to appear except in limited countries, so that if one of my clients shares the forwarding http link (by ngrok) of my website page to someone outside the specified countries, the page does not show. How can I achieve that on ngrok or if i can't do that on ngrok. Is there another way.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions/pointers:

- Buy real hosting, that can firewall/limit traffic based on countries
- build a VPS server solution yourself..

But then again, if you want to show a website ONLY to certain people:

- put it behind Authentication or share it with a special token...
- there are many solutions with which you can accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Heyo. I work at ngrok you can use the IP restrictions module https://ngrok.com/docs/cloud-edge/modules/ip-restrictions/ if that works for you, or you can use OAuth for free with ngrok, too. https://ngrok.com/docs/cloud-edge/modules/oauth/